# How to set up a repeater network using c60 as main router and TL-WR940n as a repeater

Tags: wireless-networking

I recently got 2 new routers one is tplink c 60 and other is tplink TL-WR940N. 
I have a 3 storey house and my main router c60 is in the 3rd floor. Now I want the 940N as a repeater or extender in the first floor. I already connected the 2 routers through cable and pluged it in the lan ports.
in my tether app the 940N is showing but when I am trying to login a message pops up and says make sure you are connected to the right wifi network, move closer to your device and then try again. if you have problem reset your device.

I have reset and tried but nothing is working, only my c60 is working fine and a extender of tplink is working, the 940N is not working as a repeater or extender.

Comment: TL-WA850RE i am using this as an extender and its working fine..i just wnt to set up the 940N as an repeater..

Comment: what version is the 940n?

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
450Mbps wireless speed is only for TL-WR940N V3 while the earlier version is 300Mbps. It is a combined wired/wireless network connection device designed specifically for small business and home office networking requirements You could easily pick up the wireless network during long-distance connection where legacy 11g products may not..

I think its a version 3..

Comment: You have incorrectly answered your own question using another account. Look up openwrt firmware and install the correct version for your 940n v3 - Then once you have installed openwrt firmware creating a repeater is very easy.

Comment: its version 6.1 and i have downloaded the latest firmware ..now lets c ...i just copied the description from amazon..so did int saw the version details..

Comment: It may be better for you to not use the 940n and buy another wa50re. far less messing about

Comment: Welcome to Super User! It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 0):

i have solved the problem..i had to reset my 2 modems and first i setup the archer c60, then i setup e
the 940n as an extender...it now works like a charm ..

Another problem was with the chrome browser as it was not letting me to open the 940n setup page as it took the archer c60 as default to the ip address..hence i used opera and it worked..

thanks for the suggestions..

Comment: how do "you" know the question is soled ("you" did not ask the question ...)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.